# Zend PHP Multiple Database Handling at Run Time

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, frameworks

I have one site using zend(verison1.1) php. I have created script that is generating dynamic database(for each company that is signing up on site home page) having some tables at run time with respective to url (of specific company) that is coming(means fetching company name string from url string). Now i want to connect that specific company to its dynamic database & fetch records from tables of it by using default database instances modals/classes.

Actually I want to make my application like SAAS(Single application having multiple databases) e.g(Basecamp.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it once using Zend_Db_Table.

The principle we used was a master database that contained generic site information, and on specific database per retailer (it was on a kind of retail communication system).

Then, based on the domain name (route) or on the route parameters, you can extends Zend_Controller_Action to handle a predispatch and create your specific DB adapter (or more precisely, this would be done in your Zend_Db_Table_Row, and you will call the method from this model inside your extended controller and set it as default if needed. You could also call your Db_Table_Row passing the database connection wherever needed.